# How to access the JSONata output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonata

I am integrating JSONata query in react js to achieve the JSON data restructuring.

```
import jsonata from "jsonata";

export const reconfigureQuery = (responseData) => {
  
    const jsonataQuery1 = `
    {
      "output": $distinct(response.{
        "enterpriseid" : enterpriseid,
        "enterprise": enterprise,
        "bookingvalue": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).bookingvalue),
        "foodmiles": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).foodmiles),
        "emissions": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).emissions)
      })
    }
    `;

   
    const evaluateQuery = (query, data) => {
      const expression = jsonata(query);
      const result = expression.evaluate(data);
      return result;
    };

    const enterprise1 = evaluateQuery(jsonataQuery1, { response: responseData });

 
    return enterprise1

};
```

but i am getting some unexpected output in the console

```
//Output i am getting in console 

[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(2) [
    {
        "enterpriseid": 53898,
        "enterprise": " Absolute F and B Facilities Management LLC ",
        "bookingvalue": 39362.3,
        "foodmiles": 19229.84,
        "emissions": 34.04
    },
    {
        "enterpriseid": 54080,
        "enterprise": "CONRAD HOTEL ABU DHABI EITHAD TOWERS",
        "bookingvalue": 0,
        "foodmiles": 3106.69,
        "emissions": 9.45
    },
]
```

Please help me in the code how i can be use the output in my application

Answer (score 1):

Use `await` and `async`

So the code would be

```
import jsonata from "jsonata";

export const reconfigureQuery = async (responseData) => {
    const jsonataQuery1 = `
    {
      "output": $distinct(response.{
        "enterpriseid" : enterpriseid,
        "enterprise": enterprise,
        "bookingvalue": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).bookingvalue),
        "foodmiles": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).foodmiles),
        "emissions": $sum($filter($$.response, function($item) {$item.enterpriseid = enterpriseid}).emissions)
      })
    }
    `;   
    const evaluateQuery = (query, data) => {
      const expression = jsonata(query);
      return expression.evaluate(data);
    };
    return evaluateQuery(jsonataQuery1, { response: responseData });
};
```

and use it like

```
const output = await reconfigureQuery(<YOUR-RESPONSE-DATA>);
console.log(output)
```